# Dual booting latest ubuntu and Vista - 3 problems

Tags: dual-boot

as the title suggests I am looking for a way to dual boot the latest release of ubuntu (but i can be flexible enough to downgrade due to resource insufficiency, maybe a suggestion as to a compatible version with my currect hardware?) and windows.

I have validated CPU-Z, all needed PC information is here: http://valid.canardpc.com/n67x8p
My question for that is what version of ubuntu would look AND run best on this hardware.

My current version of windows is windows vista SP2. It is installed on one WD800 Western Digital Black drive. I also installed two "storage" seagate barracuda drives; one 80gb, one 40gb. I thought since 40GB is proportional to what vista requires and what ubuntu requires, I could go ahead and install it on that drive. But, there's a problem: I tried the boot media, when i "try" it out, the screen is blank. would love some help on that too, before i go ahead and dual boot.

Now, Once that problem is solved, I would love steps as to how to install ubuntu on one drive, while keeping my windows installation untouched, and have a grub boot menu to choose from the drives.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at a lightweight distro like Lubuntu or Xubuntu that isn't as resource-hungry as the Gnome DE that will run comfortably on a single-core Pentium. I'd also search through the posts here regarding problems with Nvidia GPUs as many times it requires either a back-port kernel or installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. Also to note, i recall trying the onboard graphics and the same problem arose. To check, I listened for the DVD drive and it was not spinning, but before I assume anything, again I will look into the nvidia problem.